# Is execution of ARM assembly in iPhone Simulator or Android Simulator possible?

Tags: android, iphone, assembly, android-emulator, ios-simulator

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to execute programs using arm assembly language in the simulators?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible in the iPhone simulator because it's a i386 application without the capability to emulate another processor. As a consequence, you have to compile your iPhone app to i386 code in order to run it in the simulator.

(I can't tell you about Android.)

Comment: This is why it's called a simulator and not an emulator.

Answer (score 6):

The Android emulator, based on QEMU, provides full ARMv5TE emulation.  ARMv6/v7, VFP, and NEON are present in the current version but I think support for those is still a little flaky.

The Android SDK is a free download, so grab a copy and see if it does what you need.

**UPDATE:** Full ARMv7-A support is available and stable.