# unable to compile .s file in XCode 4.5

Tags: xcode, assembly

I'm trying to compile a .s file containing the following code:

```
.text
.globl memcpy_armneon
memcpy_armneon:
    pld [r1, #0xC0]
    vldm r1!,{d0-d7}
    vstm r0!,{d0-d7}
    subs r2,r2,#0x40
    bge memcpy_armneon
```

but XCode 4.5 complains:

"LLVM GCC 4.2 error No such instruction: 'pld [r1,'. Is there a way to compile this?

Comment: Is that the real error?  Where's the space between `pld` and `[`?

Comment: What architecture are you compiling for?  The ARM ARM tells me that instruction is only in ARMv6T2 and ARMv7.

Comment: The "Architectures" build setting is ARMV7. The same error occurs for the vldm, vstm, and bge lines.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it's psychic debugging time.  I have Xcode 4.6 here, and it doesn't appear to even *have* an ARM version of LLVM GCC:

```
$ gcc -arch armv7 -c -o example.o example.s 
llvm-gcc-4.2: error trying to exec '/usr/bin/../llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/arm-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2': execvp: No such file or directory
```

That leads me to believe that you're handing this code to an Intel assembler.  In fact, I get precisely that error wording for your file when doing just that:

```
$ gcc -c -o example.o example.s 
example.s:5:no such instruction: `pld [r1,'
example.s:6:no such instruction: `vldm r1!,{d0-d7}'
example.s:7:no such instruction: `vstm r0!,{d0-d7}'
example.s:8:too many memory references for `sub'
example.s:9:no such instruction: `bge memcpy_armneon'
```

You might want to use clang so that you can actually use an ARM assembler:

```
clang -arch armv7 -c -o example.o example.s
```

Comment: hmm.. to my knowledge I'm using the default XCode settings. Do you know how I can get XCode to use that commandline for the .s file? I switched the Build Options setting to use the Apple LLVM compiler 4.1  and the build log shows it's now using clang with a huge list of options.

Comment: Not yet. I modified the compiler flags for the .s file to try to get XCode to use those arguments but it still insists on using a huge set of options and just appends the new arguments to them. You can't use armv7 here because in this case it's being compiled for the x86 simulator. Sigh.

Comment: Well, there's your problem.  Even if you *do* manage to assemble this ARM assembly code, how is it possibly going to integrate with the simulator, which as you mention is an x86 program?  You need to take a different approach!

Comment: I was rather hoping that the simulator would run ARM assembly, but looking at the docs this is optimistic since it's a simulator rather than an emulator. Thanks for your help. This is another post that ran into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802461/is-execution-of-arm-assembly-in-iphone-simulator-or-android-simulator-possible